# Unhandled promise rejection error value is not defined in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

We are trying to fix this create user controller in Node.js Express. The problem is that when you click sign up in the front end it throws this error:
Unhandled promise rejection error value is not defined. Shows on line 28 but looks that's not the main issue. Here is the code:

```
async CreateUser(req, res) {
    const userEmail = await User.findOne({
      email: req.body.email
    });
    if (userEmail) {
      return res
        .status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
        .json({ message: 'Email already exist' });
    }

    const userName = await User.findOne({
      username: req.body.username
    });
    if (userName) {
      return res
        .status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
        .json({ message: 'Username already exist' });
    }

    return bcrypt.hash(value.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) {
        return res
          .status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
          .json({ message: 'Error hashing password' });
      }
      const body = {
        username: value.username,
        email: value.email,
        password: hash
      };
      User.create(body)
        .then(user => {
          res
            .status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
            .json({ message: 'User created successfully', user, token });
        })
        .catch(() => {
          res
            .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .json({ message: 'Error occured' });
        });
    });
  },
```

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error :  Unhandled promise rejection error **`value is not defined`**.

in your code see : where is **value** ? , it should be `req.body.password`

```
return bcrypt.hash(value.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) {
        return res
          .status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
          .json({ message: 'Error hashing password' });
      }
      const body = {
        username: value.username,
        email: value.email,
        password: hash
      };
```

code to update :

```
return bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
          if (err) {
            return res
              .status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
              .json({ message: 'Error hashing password' });
          }
          const body = {
            username: req.body.username,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hash
          };
```

Comment: It's  stopping on this line now:  .json({ message: 'Error occured' });
when I submit the form on front end

Comment: try console.log(err)

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: `res
            .status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
            .json({ message: 'User created successfully', user, token });` ......where is token ???

Comment: `res.status(HttpStatus.CREATED) .json({ message: 'User created successfully', user });` ...try this

Comment: check your database , user is created or not ?

Comment: Thanks. It's solved. I found this code from the tutorial but didn't look carefully while adding and removing some variables.